# Скрыть блок при свайпе/скролле

Tags: javascript

Ниже приведенный код скрывает блок по клику или тапу вне блока. Как скрыть блок при прокрутке/свайпе?

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
 var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");
 if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
  container.hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: То есть всегда когда скроллится ? или в определенном месте при скролле?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan в идеале, конечно, при скролле вне блока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всегда при скролле можно сделать так:

```js
$('html, body').bind('scroll',function (e) {
  var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");
  //if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
  container.hide();
  //}
});
```